# How to use extra time varying discrete inputs in Ode45?

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration, ode45

For example as shown in the function below: Where `Ts` is the variable with initial value, while `Qu` is input but it changes with time having specific values defined in the matrix.

M-file:

```
function Ts=temp(t,Ts,Qu)
Ts=Qu/(1500*4190)-12*10^6/(1500*4190)-11.1*3600*(Ts-20)/(1500*4190);
```

I am using in this way:

```
Qu=[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 21 41 60 75]
 for j=1:12
 Qu=Qu(t);
 [t,Ts]=ode45(@(t,Ts)temp(t,Ts,Qu),(1:1:12),45)
 end
```

But it is giving an error. Please explain how to use the inputs with changing time with this example.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: This one:

Error using odearguments (line 90)
@(T,TS)TEMP(T,TS,QU) must return a column vector.

Error in ode45 (line 115)
    odearguments(FcnHandlesUsed, solver_name, ode, tspan, y0, options, varargin);

Comment: See http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/97074-how-do-i-solve-an-ode-with-time-dependent-parameters-in-matlab. Google also returns loads of hits on the same topic, quite a few on SO as well.